# practice Java with intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm a complete newbie, I'm practicing with the Arrays. When writing String myArray[] I get an error in the square brackets. I am literally copying the screen of the video that I use to learn and I get 3 types of errors, which are: Variable 'myArray' is assigned but never accessed, Local variable 'myArray' has C-style array type declaration and The value 'new String [3]' assigned to 'myArray' is never used. How can I solve it?. Thanks.

```java
public class variables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myArray[]; // The problem it's here
        myArray = new String [3];

    }
}
```

I tried changing several characters but it doesn't work, I hope I can find a solution and continue learning. I know it's a very basic question but I don't want to get discouraged with the idea of ​​learning to program.

Comment: You should learn to differentiate between errors and warnings

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings.  Which one of those warnings is unclear or do you think is incorrect?  What's stopping you from continuing to write your code?

Comment: Those are warnings, Intellij is warning you for possible logical errors when it detects suspicious code. The java style to declare array is `String[] myArray` (check the argument of your main method). The other warnings are pretty self explanatory - you never do anything with the variable you declared.

Comment: `String[] myArray;` is the appropriate form in Java. All of these are warnings that do not prevent compiling and running the code. The two other warnings related to "never accessed" or "never used" is because you haven't written code to use those things yet. In other words, they're a warning that you're not done! You'll run into errors down the line: compiler errors prevent compiling the code, and runtime errors "prevent" normal operation of the code.

Comment: Before posting here: (a) Search Stack Overflow. You would have found many examples. (b) Study the relevant portion of [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) provided by Oracle Corp free of cost.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are **no errors in your code**.

However **there are warnings**.

The word warnings itself should be clear but in a brief, it is your IDE telling you - "Hey, your codes gonna run but this line is unnecessary" or "This is something that can make your code behave like you want it to".

This may be for just a *few programmers* (like me for example), you may be annoyed by the underlines in your code so there are multiple ways to fix this.

**A) Dealing with the warning-**
Dealing with the warning is probably the most simplest way to fix warnings.

Lets take the warning *"Local variable 'myArray' has C-style array type declaration"* as an example, for some reason IntelliJ prefers to keep the square brackets after the class rather than after the variable name like so `String[] myArray;`

**B) Using `@SuppressWarnings`-** SuppressWarnings is an annotation that helps you avoid these annoying warnings for example

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String[] myArray;
```

There is a shortcut on IntelliJ. Keep the text cursor on the warning, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, Click on the three dots at the right side of the box, and choose a suppress option.

**C) Configuring IDE settings**- Choose what warnings you want or don't want

Keep the text cursor on the warning, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, Click on the three dots at the right side of the box and press on the "Edit inspection profile setting", then turn off whatever you don't want to give you a warning. Remember that the error you used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on will be selected, which saves you a bunch of time.

Comment: _"for some reason IntelliJ prefers to keep the square brackets after the class"_ not just IntelliJ. That style is the most commonly used one in Java style guides.